# Is there anyway to add one value at the bottom of a React Table?

Tags: html, reactjs

I create a table with all the value. Now I just need to only add one number which is the total of the entire co2/kg at the bottom of the  co2/kg column but I am having trouble adding it in the table format. Is there anyway I can add it?

```
<table class="table mt-5 text-center">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>UOM</th>
                    <th>Density</th>
                    <th>CO2/kg</th>
                    <th>Carbon</th>
                    <th>Footprint</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {/* testing.map */}
                  {descrition.map((descrition) => (
                    <tr key={descrition.id}>
                      <td>{descrition.food}</td>
                      <td>{descrition.quantity}</td>
                      <td>{descrition.uom}</td>
                      <td>{descrition.density}</td>
                      <td>{descrition.carbon}</td>
                      <td>{carbonCategory(descrition.carbon)}</td>
                      <td>{carbonCategory(descrition.carbon)}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

[Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY7VJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add empty cells up until you reach the desired column and then array.reduce the values you need. Just adds all the values together. Here's a https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-wave-tjs89y?file=/src/App.js:1318-1417

```
{description.reduce((acc, item) => {return acc + item.carbon;}, 0)}
```